# Heroku + Rails: Heroku connecting to wrong database from CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently created a basic level database for my rails app and I noticed while I was attempting to run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

from the command line, that it was connecting to my old database.  How do you control which database heroku connects to from the `heroku run` command?

Comment: Go to your heroku app dashboard and check for postgres plugin..see which db is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to specify the database when running Heroku Rake commands, but you could set a specific database as primary (and thus automatically connecting to it when running said commands).

Run `heroku pg:info`, which should output something like (two databases should be listed in your case):

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:           Ronin
Status:         Available
Data Size:      26.1 MB
Tables:         5
PG Version:     9.5.3
Connections:    2
Fork/Follow:    Available
Rollback:       Unsupported
Created:        2012-05-02 21:54 UTC
Maintenance:    not required (Mondays 23:00 to Tuesdays 03:00 UTC)
Infrastructure: Legacy
```

You can then choose a database to promote:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL
```

You can read more in [this Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql).

Comment: hmmm.  I've already done that and the correct DB is promoted.  I only thought there was an issue here because my most recent migrations were not fired when I called `heroku run rake db:migrate` but maybe something else is going on

Comment: It's possible that these migrations were never committed properly to Heroku. When running `rake db:migrate`, the current schema version (aka `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170605195958)` in `schema.rb`) might skip over certain migrations based on the timestamp in the migration filename. Run `heroku pg:psql` then `\d` to view all tables on Heroku, which you can then compare to your local database to see which migrations are missing.